# Specify two default values for a single attribute in django model

Tags: python, django-models

I have a model called AttendenceData in my models.py and it has attributes employee_id, type and datetime.

The type attribute is a stringfield with two possible values IN/OUT.

How can i do this in django model?

TIA

Comment: They're not defaults, they're [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#choices).

Comment: Two default values aren't possible: default is singular, how can there be two? EDIT: If you want to put one of `IN/OUT`, depending on your business logic, then you maybe should override your model's `save()`.

Comment: Yeah i gottu know that they are choices and there can be no two default values. Thanks for the response